# Powershell - Why does $ENV | GET-MEMBER not work?

Tags: powershell

I come from a C, C++, C#, python background so i'm applying this thought pattern to Powershell which i'm learning from scratch but I'm a little confused so far as at first glance it seems to be inconsistent and does not follow a fixed base class type structure for all objects so that things can be queried in a consistent manner.

The following works fine:

```
   $host | get-member
   $env:username
```

So $env is a valid object but this does not work:

```
   $env | get-member
```

These also do not work:

```
   $env.gettype()
   dir $env
   dir $env:
```

but this type query on $host does so I'm assuming $host is a .net variable but $env is not?

```
   $host.gettype()
```

I found that env: also works with dir (aka get-childitem) but this colon is yet another type of notation i'm unfamiliar with and things are starting to get very confusing now. This does not seem to be a string format in this case which I have seen some google posts about so what is it? It behaves like a member selection or dictionary key specifier. If it is a member selector or dictionary key then i would expect get-member to work because it is a standard object.

This outputs the variables and values that I wanted but I don't understand why this syntax is used. This is not DOS syntax either so what's going on here?

```
   dir env:
```

But dir $env seems to equate to dir $env:userprofile???? why?

Therefore $host appears to be a .net object but $env or env: is something else completely different and I've no idea what object type it is in the grand scheme of things and cannot seem to query it's type with by conventional means. Initial thoughts are that it is a list object of sorts because get-childitem works with it but other than that I'm completely lost.

I'm clearly missing something here so can someone steer me in the right direction please?

Comment: Because you does not have `$env` variable. `$env` and `$env:something` is two different unrelated things.

Comment: OK, so as I wrote above what is $env if it is not a variable? It seems env: is actually a drive but $env and $env:username is something else and I still am unsure what that is.

Comment: `$env` is variable, but you do not have one, because you are not assign something to it, like `$env = 'something'`. `$env:username` is equivalent of `Get-Content env:username`, where `env:username` is PowerShell path of PowerShell provider item. It work with any provider, which implement content cmdlets: `${C:\Windows\System.ini}` or `$function:prompt`.

Comment: Ah OK I see what you are saying, what I find confusing though is that $env is indeed not set to anything in my case but $env:username does actually work. I'm getting confused because to me it logically reads as "the username property of the env variable". It's handy knowing that $env:username = ${env:username} = get-content env:username so thanks for the heads-up on that. Personally I would say $env:username should not be allowed as valid syntax so that it is not confused with a variable name. Thanks for the clarification though. :-)

Answer (score 4):

`Get-Help 'about_Providers' -ShowWindow` shows that `env:` is *drive* in [*Environment* Provider](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847860.aspx), i.e. one of [Windows PowerShell *providers*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847791.aspx).

> **BUILT-IN PROVIDERS**: Windows PowerShell includes a set of built-in
>   providers that you can use to access the different types of data
>   stores.
>
> ```
> Provider      Drive         Data store
> --------      -----         ----------
> Alias         Alias:        Windows PowerShell aliases
> Certificate   Cert:         x509 certificates for digital signatures
> Environment   Env:          Windows environment variables
> FileSystem    *             File system drives, directories, and files
> Function      Function:     Windows PowerShell functions
> Registry      HKLM:, HKCU:  Windows registry
> Variable      Variable:     Windows PowerShell variables
> WSMan         WSMan:        WS-Management configuration information
>
> * The FileSystem drives vary on each system.
> ```
>
> You can also create your own Windows PowerShell providers, and you can
>   install providers that others develop. To list the providers that are 
>   available in your session, type: `get-psprovider`.

That's why `Get-ChildItem env:` works in contrary to <s>`dir $env:`</s>, <s>`dir $env`</s> etc.

Answer (score 4):

First thing to note is that `$env` and `$env:username` are not related. `$env` is just a variable and normally it does not exists, because nobody assign anything to it. Using colon in variable name (like `$env:username`, with exception to some predefined prefixes: `global:`, `script:`, `local:`, `private:` and `variable:`) is a special syntax, which allows to access to PowerShell provider item content with variable syntax. It works with any PowerShell provider which implement content cmdlets: `${C:\Windows\System.ini}` or `$function:prompt`. That syntax is equivalent of calling of `Get-Content` or `Set-Content` for given PowerShell path.

Comment: Nice answer. There is something that is not clear to me. Namely, if we want to find all build in variables, we may use `Get-ChildItem -Path variable:`. So, why the resulting list does not contain $env,

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents: 
Try `get-psdrive` and you will get something like:

```
Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root
Env                                    Environment
```

So it seems to be something like a driver in batch.